# jquery - Collapsing / Expanding divs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nested, expand

Trying to create collapsible / expandable divs using jQuery, but it's not working for me at all...  Each h3 should expand/collapse the div beneath it, and I'm not sure why this isn't working...  Granted,  *is* a heavily nested div, but I thought that the script below would find the uforms class regardless of how much other markup is on the page when it loads and then do what it's supposed to do...

Here's the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('div.uforms:eq(1)> div:gt(-1)').hide();
        $('div.uforms:eq(1)> h3').click(function() {
                $(this).next('div:hidden').slideDown('fast').siblings('div:visible').slideUp('fast');
        });
});
```

And, the markup (minus all the stuff that's actually inside the `<div></div>`, because it's a lot of form stuff...)

```
<div class="uforms">
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <div></div>

  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <div></div>

  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the point of :gt(-1) and what are your intentions with :eq(1)? Odd to see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) is what you are trying to achive

I highly recommend the jQueryUI framework.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agreed, no point re-inventing the wheel, just re-use someone else's ;)

Comment: *Except* if you're not already using jQueryUI, then you're adding a minimum of 32k (using a custom build) just for an accordion.

Answer (score 4):

You're selectors are just wrong.  You don't need `eq` or `gt`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordion > div').hide();
    $('.accordion> h3').click(function() {
        $(this).next('div:hidden').slideDown('fast').siblings('div:visible').slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

I would change the class identified to something more general so you can reuse this in other places.

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div>cactuspants! <div>I am an inner div</div></div>

    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div>Hats</div>

    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div>Hi!</div>
</div>
```

Also, others have suggested that you just use jQueryUI, which is completely valid, unless you're not already using it *or* intend to use it for additional features.  A s3 line function beats including an addition 32K library (the size of the minimally necessary components in a customized build).

Answer (score 1):

I just use the accordion widget with just one **div** inside.

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true
});

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>test 1 2 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Include this css link:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
```